# Add external library and jar in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Anyone can tell how to add external library and jar file in Android Studio, I know in Eclipse you can Right click -> Property -> Java Build Path, but what to do in Android Studio ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding external library or dependency, you can either edit `gradle` file for app manually, or you can do it by `Project Structure`.

- Edit `Gradle` File of app

Open gradle file of app, you can add/edit in the `dependencies` tag,

[image]

the first line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` indicates that it will include the jar files in this project;

- in `Project Structure`

`File` -> `Project Structure`, and in the pop-up window, click `app` in the left list, then click `dependencies`, in the top-right corner, click `+` to add new dependency.

[image]